# Make xzoom float in i3wm

Tags: x11, i3

I'm trying to configure *i3* so that `xzoom` is always launched in floating mode.

The problem is that xzoom's window does not have a `WM_CLASS` and its `WM_NAME` is not set at window creation, but after a small delay.

Here is what the properties look like for the first few ms:

```
$ xzoom & sleep .01; xprop -id 0x2200001
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
        window state: Normal
        icon window: 0x0
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "xzoom"
```

As you can see, the only thing that tells it apart is the `WM_ICON_NAME`.
After a few ms the title is added:

```
$ xprop
WM_NAME(STRING) = "xzoom x4"
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
        window state: Normal
        icon window: 0x0
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "xzoom"
```

If I match the window using `WM_NAME`, the screen flashes horribly, as the other windows are re-arranged before falling back to their positions:

```
for_window [title="xzoom*"] floating enable
```

I tried looking for a [command criterion](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#command_criteria) that would look at the `WM_ICON_NAME`, but I couldn't find any.

Is there an alternative way to start this program in floating mode?

Comment: If you're willing to write a wrapper script, you can wait for the necessary properties to be set. I did a similar thing [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474300/17409).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a WM_CLASS to xzoom by recompiling it with

```
    XChangeProperty(dpy, win, XA_WM_CLASS, XA_STRING, 8,
                    PropModeReplace,
                    (unsigned char *)progname, strlen(progname));
```

on the line after where `XA_WM_ICON_NAME` is set.

Then, `for_window [instance="xzoom"] floating enable`
worked for me in my i3 config!

It's great that this old software still works so well :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could try adding the following line to i3 config which should correctly match the window title:

```
for_window [title="^xzoom"] border none; floating enable
```

That said, it also makes me happy to see that compiling a customization is always an option.